# Background Image в Zdog

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Здравствуйте пользователи stackoverflow. Наткнулся на проблему на js в zdog не могу указать изображение как фон грани в box, с установкой цвета фона проблем не возникает, только с Background image. Спасибо.

```
new Zdog.Box({
    addTo: illo,
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    depth: 250,
    color: orange,

    topFace: backgroundImage = 'res/grass.png',

    leftFace: garnet,
    rightFace: garnet,
    bottomFace: eggplant,
    stroke: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно исходники библиотеки

```
Box.prototype.setFace = function( faceName, value ) {
   var rectProperty = faceName + 'Rect';
   var rect = this[ rectProperty ];
   // remove if false
   if ( !value ) {
     this.removeChild( rect );
     return;
   }
   // update & add face
   var options = this.getFaceOptions( faceName );
   options.color = typeof value == 'string' ? value : this.color;

   if ( rect ) {
     // update previous
     rect.setOptions( options );
   } else {
     // create new
     rect = this[ rectProperty ] = new BoxRect( options );
   }
   rect.updatePath();
   this.addChild( rect );
};
```

Особенно вот эту строку:

```
options.color = typeof value == 'string' ? value : this.color;
```

Это значит, что `topFace` (и другие `face`) проставляет только цвет для выбранной стороны.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.